# Understanding Angular2 Dependency Injection in modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have written a feature module , and below is the code

`app.ticket.service.ts`, this is my service which i would  like to inject

```
'use strict';    
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core' 

Injectable()
export class AppTicketService {    

    SaveTicket(): string {
return "service saved ticket";
    }       

}
```

`app.tickets.module.ts`, this is my feature module

```
'use strict';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/app.shared.module';
import { AppCreatTicketComponent } from './app.create-ticket.component';
//-- import services
import { AppTicketService } from './app.ticket.service';

//-- import routing
import { ticketRouting } from './app.ticket.routing';
  @NgModule({
    declarations:[ AppCreatTicketComponent],
     imports:[ SharedModule,
               ticketRouting],
     exports:[],
     providers:[AppTicketService]
 })

 export class TicketsModule { }
```

app.create-ticket.component.ts , this is my component ,
which belongs to feature module

```
 'use strict';
 import { Component , OnInit , Inject} from '@angular/core';    

 //-- import service
 import { AppTicketService } from './app.ticket.service';

 @Component({
 templateUrl: '/tickets/create'
 })

 export class AppCreatTicketComponent implements OnInit{

 ngOnInit(){}

 constructor(public service1 :AppTicketService) {
    let test = this.service1.SaveTicket();      
 }

 }
```

At runtime I am getting:

> "Can't resolve all parameters for AppCreatTicketComponent:" error in browser console

What needs to be modified to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this issue I had to modify constructor paramter in app.create-ticket.component.ts file

**Original**

```
constructor(public service1 :AppTicketService)
```

**Modified**

```
constructor(@Inject(AppTicketService) private service1: AppTicketService)
```

You can find reason for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36363279/angular-2-di-not-working-cannot-resolve-all-parameters-for)